# C Linux Tracing all function calls including function inside library

Tags: c, linux

i have program like

```
int main()
{
  char *ptr = malloc(2);
  free(ptr);
}
```

So i just want to trace of all function calls happening inside the program ,till system call

like

```
malloc
   |____ libc( sme_fn)
           |
           |__sme_system_call
```

Could you please tell some way to get this ?

Comment: What about running your program with `ltrace -S`?

Comment: Thank you FatalError :),And i tried as like you told 

but you can see in the below output,call jump to SYS_brk after malloc.

but I was really more interested in libaray function flow inside malloc so that i can understand how glibc malloc works. 

So is there any way to get more details between malloc from my function and sys_brk? 
`SYS_munmap(0xb77a5000, 68105) 
__libc_start_main(0x80483f4, 1, 0xbfd9c8d4, 0x8048420, 0x8048480 <unfinished ...>
malloc(2 <unfinished ...>
SYS_brk(NULL)
SYS_brk(0x0854b000)
<... malloc resumed> ) 
free(0x0852a008) 
SYS_exit_group(0 <no return ...>`

Answer (score 2):

As you know, "system calls" come in two flavors:

- Calls directly to the operating system ("open", "close", "fork", "exec", "exit", etc)
- Standard C runtime functions for the platform ("printf()", "malloc()", "free(), etc.)

You can view the former with "[strace](http://www.aboutlinux.info/2006/05/strace-very-powerful-troubleshooting.html)".

You can view (at least calls into) the latter with [gdb](http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/GDB-Commands.html).

You can look at the complete implementation, and all internals, directly from the source code:

- [Gnu C Library](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/)
- [Linux kernel](http://www.kernel.org/)

Finally, if you're having issues with "malloc()", "[valgrind](http://www.cprogramming.com/debugging/valgrind.html)" is (one of several) very, very useful tools to consider.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using gcc, compile with -pg and then use the gprof command.

Or, if you're on Linux, you can use [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/news/) to do something similar without recompiling.

Both tools should give you call graphs, which is what you're looking for.